# Como bloquear o duplo clique em um vídeo?

Tags: vídeo, click, fullscreen

Criei uma página com um vídeo setado na resolução e layout que quero, mas ao receber um duplo clique ele entra em modo *fullscreen*, eu gostaria de desabilitar isso. Usei o *script*:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("*").dblclick(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

Mas mesmo assim o navegador(Chrome) aceita o clique duplo e coloca o vídeo em *fullscreen*.

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro utilizar uma API JS para isso, pois esse evento ainda está com problemas em alguns browsers... Uma simples e boa api para vídeo é o [video.js](http://docs.videojs.com/) nele você consegue bloquear o fullscreen perfeitamente, veja o exemplo:

HTML:

```
  <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="340" height="268">
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm'>
  </video>
```

JS:

```
videojs('my_video_1', {
  controlBar: {
    fullscreenControl: false
  }
});
```

[Exemplo](http://jsbin.com/vegogeyata/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Desculpe a demora, implementei sua ajuda, deu muito certo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
$("body").on('dblclick', function(){
   return false;
});
```

Se for um `iframe` pode usar:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/@(item.VideoUrl)"></iframe>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo.